# Laravel 5 - Storage Adapter Extending Will Not Work

Tags: php, laravel, ftp

For some reason I cannot extend the Storage Class like the example in the docs.

I have been trying to create an FTP adapter because it is required for the project I am working on.

Here is the Service Provider I have created

```
<?php namespace herbals\Providers;

use Storage;
use Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use League\Flysystem\Filesystem;
use League\Flysystem\Adapter\Ftp as FTPAdapter;

class FTPFileSystemServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

public function boot()
{
    Storage::extend('ftp', function($app, $config)
    {
        $client = new FTPAdapter(array(
            'host' => env('FTP_HOST') || '',
            'username' => env('FTP_USERNAME') || '',
            'password' => env('FTP_PASSWORD') || '',

            'port' => env('FTP_PORT') || '',
            'root' => env('FTP_ROOT') || '/',
            'passive' => true,
            'ssl' => true,
            'timeout' => 30,
        ));
        $filesystem = new Filesystem($client);
        return $filesystem;
    });
}

public function register()
{
    //
}

}
```

Here is the error I keep getting

```
ErrorException in FilesystemManager.php line 232:
call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback,     class 'Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemAdapter' does not have a method   'createDriver'
in FilesystemManager.php line 232
at HandleExceptions->handleError('2', 'call_user_func_array() expects     parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class    'Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemAdapter' does not have a method 'createDriver'',    '/home/vagrant/Code/herbals/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemManager.php', '232', array('method' => 'createDriver',   'parameters' => array(null)))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(FilesystemAdapter),    'createDriver'), array(null)) in FilesystemManager.php line 232
at FilesystemManager->__call('createDriver', array(null)) in FilesystemManager.php line 97
at FilesystemManager->createDriver(null) in FilesystemManager.php line 97
at FilesystemManager->resolve('ftp') in FilesystemManager.php line 79
at FilesystemManager->get('ftp') in FilesystemManager.php line 68
at FilesystemManager->disk('ftp') in Facade.php line 210
at Facade::__callStatic('disk', array('ftp')) in routes.php line 26
at Storage::disk('ftp') in routes.php line 26
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are making a little mistake here, make sure you have the ftp drivers and its details (host, username,password ) in /config/filesystem.php  and reference them in your provider using $config['host'] and so on...

After playing with the api for some time , I was able to figure it out , now follow these instructions : In you /config/filesystem.php , add the new driver settings like :

```
'ftp' => [
             'driver'   => 'ftp',
             'host'     =>'ftp-host',
             'username' => 'ftp-username',
             'password' => 'ftp-pass',
             'port'     => 21,
             'ssl'      => false,
        ],
```

Next we will create an Ftp Filemanager Driver Service Provider in /app/Providers ,save the file FtpFilesystemServiceProvider.php .. Below is how mine looks like

```
<?php 

namespace App\Providers;

use Storage;
use League\Flysystem\Filesystem;
use League\Flysystem\Adapter\Ftp as FtpAdapter;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

    class FtpFilesystemServiceProvider extends  ServiceProvider {

        //boot 
        public function boot()
        {
        Storage::extend('ftp',function($app, $config){

        //init the client 
        $client = new FtpAdapter($config);

        //lets now call the obj 
        $ftpFileSystem = new Filesystem($client);

        //return 
        return $ftpFileSystem;
        }); 

        }//end boot 


         public function register()
        {
            //
        }


    }
```

After which we will edit /config/app.php and add the service provider to providers  array so you will add the code below to the list of providers:

```
'App\Providers\FtpFilesystemServiceProvider',
```

We are done, you are off to go , yo can call the storage like this

```
Storage::disk("ftp");
```

or set ftp as your default driver , ....